# I have installed ubuntu and don't know what happened it has erased my Windows. My all drives

Tags: dual-boot

Accidentally I have erased my windows while installing ubuntu. How can I recover or load in to windows without actually reinstalling windows

Comment: If the Windows partition has been erased, then it's erased. So the answer to your question is: You can't - sorry. If you need to recover erased partition, this is a job for a data recovery expert (which can be costly). Also unfortunately, the question itself is seemingly not about Ubuntu.

Comment: How you restore your prior setup will clearly depend on what backup strategy you put into place to achieve this; how are we to know?

Comment: Because I am confused that I did choose the dual boot yet it has erased windows and also I tried boot loader but no Luck